# jsoup parse from website redirect

Tags: java, ajax, parsing, jsoup

I am parsing from this [url](https://jizdenky.studentagency.cz/Booking/from/1763018002/to/10202038/tarif/REGULAR/departure/20160711/retdep/20160711/return/false/ropen/false/credit/false/class/2), but I have a problem with ajax load. When I parse this website it show me only body without response I need body of elememt `ticket_lists`. I dont know how redirect on this website is working. I tried debug js in debugger but without success. I am using jsoup. It is possible?

Thank you

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://jizdenky.studentagency.cz/Booking/from/1763018002/to/10202038/tarif/REGULAR/departure/20160711/retdep/20160711/return/false/ropen/false/credit/false/class/2")
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();
Map<String,String> cookies = response.cookies();

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://jizdenky.studentagency.cz/Booking/from/1763018002/to/10202038/tarif/REGULAR/departure/20160711/retdep/20160711/return/false/ropen/false/credit/false/class/2?1")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36")
                .cookies(cookies)
                .get();
System.out.print(doc.body());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open your browser's developer tools, You'll see that after requesting the first page, the browser is redirected, and send (among other things) an `XHR` request (which is actually an `AJAX`):
[image]
The response to that request contains the information you need.
Check the parameters that the browser is sending and do the same.